# Java error: unreachable statement when create new linked list node

Tags: java, linked-list, unreachable-code, unreachable-statement

I wrote a program for merge two linkedlist so I create a dummyHead first. But the compiler returns me an error: unreachable statement. I searched it on Internet but still don't understand why is it.

The code is :

```
/**
 * class ListNode {
 *   public int value;
 *   public ListNode next;
 *   public ListNode(int value) {
 *     this.value = value;
 *     next = null;
 *   }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {
  public ListNode merge(ListNode one, ListNode two) {
    if(one == null && two != null){
      return two;
    }else if(one != null && two == null){
      return one;
    }else{
      return null;
    }
    
    ListNode dummyHead = new ListNode(-1);
    ListNode cur_one = one;
    ListNode cur_two = two;
    ListNode dummyCur = dummyHead;
    while(cur_one.next == null || cur_two.next == null){
      if(cur_one.value <= cur_two.value){
        dummyCur.next = cur_one;
        cur_one = cur_one.next;
      }else{
        dummyCur.next = cur_two;
        cur_two = cur_two.next;
      }
      dummyCur = dummyCur.next;
    }
    
    if(cur_one.next != null){
      dummyCur.next = cur_one.next;
    }
    if(cur_two.next != null){
      dummyCur.next = cur_two.next;
    }
    
    return dummyHead.next;
  }
}
```

The error information is :

> error:java.io.IOException: /Solution.java:21: error: unreachable statement
>
> ```
> ListNode dummyHead = new ListNode(-1);
> ```

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: It means that your program will be terminated before that statement in any case

Comment: Just as the error states, that line of code (and subsequently everything after it) is unreachable.  And, as a result, is unnecessary.  Under what logical condition do you expect that line of code to ever be reached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line is never executed because of your if/else if/else conditional:

```
if(one == null && two != null){
  return two;
} else if(one != null && two == null){
  return one;
} else{
  return null;
}
```

Based on this conditional, two, one, or null is returned before line 21 can be executed.

You'll want to remove the else to allow the method to continue executing.

Answer (score 2):

`else {
    return null;
}`

The last else condition returns null before that line. Remove last else condition if you expect rest of function to be used.

Answer (score 1):

In your first if-statement you leave the method with an early exit under all possible circumstances due to the last else-block. That’s why none of the following statements will ever be executed.